# What is causing the message "IndexError: list index out of range"?

Tags: python, list, random

I am comfortable with python but I can't figure out why this error is showing up because of my code:

```
import random
inp = input('Enter: ')
inp = str(inp)
char = 0
key = []
list = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%&*?+-')

if inp == 'New':
    while char < len(list):
        rand = random.randint(0, len(list))
        key.append(list[rand])
        char = char + 1
print(key)
```

The code won't always print the list "key" and instead give me the error "IndexError: list index out of range". How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`randint` is inclusive, so it will include the actual value of the length of the list in the random values, which can cause out of range index. For example, if you have a list that has length 8, it can give you the value 8, even though the max index you have can only be 7.

To fix, you just need to use:

```
rand = random.randint(0, len(list) - 1)
```

EDIT:

As @DeepSpace mentioned, you can also use [`random.choice(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice). And also try to avoid using the built-in `list` as a variable name.

Comment: While technically correct, you can add that OP can simply use `random.choice(list)`, and while at it, use another name than the built-in `list`.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't realized that. It makes sense because a list starts at 0. Thanks!